# responsive design strange behaviour

Tags: css, codepen

can someone take a look at this 
[this codepen](https://codepen.io/Ratko_Solaja/pen/ztxkw) ?

I didn't write it, but I can't figure out this responsiveness behaviour... when I use codepen or F12 to reduce the size of the screen it works, BUT when I open it on mobile phone or open it in inspect mode (device under 800px) its not displayed in single row... any ideas how to fix it?

this is responsiveness code that is written

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    #conference-timeline .timeline-start,
    #conference-timeline .timeline-end {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #conference-timeline .conference-center-line {
        margin-left: 0;
        left: 50px;
    }
    .timeline-article .meta-date {
        margin-left: 0;
        left: 20px;
    }
    .timeline-article .content-left-container,
    .timeline-article .content-right-container {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 110px;
        min-height: 53px;
    }
    .timeline-article .content-left-container {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .timeline-article .content-left,
    .timeline-article .content-right {
        padding: 10px 25px;
        min-height: 65px;
    }
    .timeline-article .content-left:before {
        content: "\f0d9";
        right: auto;
        left: -8px;
    }
    .timeline-article .content-right:before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `codepen` issue. Well, it's not really an issue but has to do with how it works in editor mode.

On mobile, codepen isn't honoring the media queries because it starts displaying its desktop version. I suppose this is so you can still edit `html`, `css`, and `JavaScript`.

However, you switch to `Full Page` mode, you can view the responsiveness of the edited design: https://codepen.io/Ratko_Solaja/full/ztxkw/

Also, note two things:

**Add meta viewport tag**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**Add CSS Reset, in this case Normalize**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Why does the responsiveness work?**

Because of for both `.content-left-container` and `.content-right-container` it adds `float:none` on the media-query.

Here is the code working:

```css
     body {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/*===== Vertical Timeline =====*/
#conference-timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 920px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#conference-timeline .timeline-start,
#conference-timeline .timeline-end {
  display: table;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #00b0bd;
  padding: 15px 23px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#conference-timeline .conference-center-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  background: #00b0bd;
  z-index: -1;
}
#conference-timeline .conference-timeline-content {
  padding-top: 67px;
  padding-bottom: 67px;
}
.timeline-article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.timeline-article .content-left-container,
.timeline-article .content-right-container {
  max-width: 44%;
  width: 100%;
}
.timeline-article .timeline-author {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #242424;
  text-align: right;
}
.timeline-article .content-left,
.timeline-article .content-right {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.03);
  padding: 27px 25px;
}
.timeline-article p {
  margin: 0 0 0 60px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #242424;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline-article p span.article-number {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 44px;
  top: 10px;
  left: -60px;
  color: #00b0bd;
}
.timeline-article .content-left-container {
  float: left;
}
.timeline-article .content-right-container {
  float: right;
}
.timeline-article .content-left:before,
.timeline-article .content-right:before{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  color: #fff;
}
.timeline-article .content-left:before {
  content: "\f0da";
  right: -8px;
}
.timeline-article .content-right:before {
  content: "\f0d9";
  left: -8px;
}
.timeline-article .meta-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  margin-left: -31px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #00b0bd;
}
.timeline-article .meta-date .date,
.timeline-article .meta-date .month {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.timeline-article .meta-date .date {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.timeline-article .meta-date .month {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
/*===== // Vertical Timeline =====*/

/*===== Resonsive Vertical Timeline =====*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) {
  #conference-timeline .timeline-start,
  #conference-timeline .timeline-end {
    margin: 0;
  }
  #conference-timeline .conference-center-line {
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 50px;
  }
  .timeline-article .meta-date {
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 20px;
  }
  .timeline-article .content-left-container,
  .timeline-article .content-right-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 110px;
    min-height: 53px;
  }
  .timeline-article .content-left-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .timeline-article .content-left,
  .timeline-article .content-right {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    min-height: 65px;
  }
  .timeline-article .content-left:before {
    content: "\f0d9";
    right: auto;
    left: -8px;
  }
  .timeline-article .content-right:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .timeline-article p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .timeline-article p span.article-number {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
/*===== // Resonsive Vertical Timeline =====*/
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Responsive Vertical Timeline</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,400italic,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<section id="conference-timeline">
    <div class="timeline-start">Start</div>
    <div class="conference-center-line"></div>
    <div class="conference-timeline-content">
      <!-- Article -->
      <div class="timeline-article">
        <div class="content-left-container">
          <div class="content-left">
            <p>When I orbited the Earth in a spaceship, I saw for the first time how beautiful our planet is. Mankind, let us preserve and increase this beauty, and not destroy it! <span class="article-number">01</span></p>
          </div>
          <span class="timeline-author">John Doe</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right-container">
          <div class="content-right">
            <p>When I orbited the Earth in a spaceship, I saw for the first time how beautiful our planet is. <span class="article-number">02</span></p>
          </div>
          <span class="timeline-author">John Doe</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-date">
          <span class="date">18</span>
          <span class="month">APR</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Article -->
      
      <!-- Article -->
      <div class="timeline-article">
        <div class="content-left-container">
          <div class="content-left">
            <p>When I orbited the Earth in a spaceship, I saw for the first time how beautiful our planet is. Mankind, let us preserve and increase this beauty, and not destroy it! <span class="article-number">01</span></p>
          </div>
          <span class="timeline-author">John Doe</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right-container">
          <div class="content-right">
            <p>When I orbited the Earth in a spaceship, I saw for the first time how beautiful our planet is. <span class="article-number">02</span></p>
          </div>
          <span class="timeline-author">John Doe</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-date">
          <span class="date">18</span>
          <span class="month">APR</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Article -->
      
      <!-- Article -->
      <div class="timeline-article">
        <div class="content-left-container">
          <div class="content-left">
            <p>When I orbited the Earth in a spaceship, I saw for the first time how beautiful our planet is. Mankind, let us preserve and increase this beauty, and not destroy it! <span class="article-number">01</span></p>
          </div>
          <span class="timeline-author">John Doe</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right-container">
          <div class="content-right">
            <p>When I orbited the Earth in a spaceship, I saw for the first time how beautiful our planet is. <span class="article-number">02</span></p>
          </div>
          <span class="timeline-author">John Doe</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-date">
          <span class="date">18</span>
          <span class="month">APR</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Article -->
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-end">End</div>
  </section>
  <!-- // Vertical Timeline -->
</body>
```

Comment: I have copy paste all of that to my local machine and have same issue... its not responsive

Comment: Be sure to add the meta viewport tag and use the same css reset as the codepen. I added a code snippet above so you can see it at work. Also, note the main thing that makes it responsive is changing the `float` on the `left` and `right` containers to `none`.

Comment: yea you are right, as soon as I added meta tag it worked, totally forgot on that